# Theme: dropdown hover menu not showing up in IE/Edge

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, sub-menu, dropdown

I'm using the theme Illdy, and the hoverable dropdown menus on the top navbar are not dropping down in IE or Edge. Firefox and Chrome appear to work. 
I've tried adding a variety of these to the additional CSS:

```
#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
visibility: visible;
}
```

```
.header-navigation .menu > li:hover > ul {
opacity: 1;
transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
visibility: visible;
}
.header-navigation .menu-item>li>ul li:hover>a {
opacity: 1;
}
```

to no avail.

The theme's original CSS pertaining to the top navbar menu is:

```
#header .top-header .header-logo {
    display: block;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#header .top-header .header-logo:hover,
#header .top-header .header-logo:focus {
    color: #f1d204;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation {
    float: right;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation > ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li {
    margin-left: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Lato";
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children a {
    padding-right: 16px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children a:after {
    content: "\f107";
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
    width: 200px;
    margin: -5px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);

    transform: translateX(-50%);

}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -3px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu:before {
    display: none;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li:first-child {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li a {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #8c9597;
    text-transform: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Lato";
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li:hover > a,
#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li:focus-within > a {
    color: #f1d204;
    border-left: 3px solid #f1d204;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li a:after {
    display: none;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
}

#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li:hover a,
#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li:focus-within a {
    color: #ffde00;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Most theme and CSS questions don't receive a lot of attention here as the focus is on custom code. You'll be better off contacting the theme developer directly, or possibly asking on StackOverflow since this is a CSS question that's not WP-specific.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go ahead and do that instead! :)